# I am not getting any error but nothing is getting inserted into my database

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, javafx

```
package application;

import java.time.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class SignUpController {

    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //private LocalDate dob;
    private String gender;
//  private Date date_of_birth;


    @FXML
    private TextField first_name;

    @FXML
    private TextField last_name;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker date;

    @FXML
    private TextField user;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField pass;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton male_rb;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton female_rb;



    @FXML
    public void submitController(ActionEvent event) throws Exception
    {       
        //ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

        fname=first_name.getText();
        lname=last_name.getText();
        username=user.getText();
        password=pass.getText();
        //dob = date.getValue();

        if(male_rb.isSelected())
        {
            gender=male_rb.getText();
        }
        else
        {
            gender=female_rb.getText();
        }

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl2","scott","root");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?);");  
            stmt.setString(1,fname);
            stmt.setString(2,lname);
        //  stmt.setDate(3,date_of_birth);
            stmt.setString(3,gender);
            stmt.setString(4,username);
            stmt.setString(5,password);

            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I am using javafx and orcl2 database 10g with jdbc 8 jar file.

The code above is for my signup page where I am getting input from textfields and storing it in local variables.Then I am using this local variables to insert into database. When I am clicking database no error or nothing is printed and no row is getting inserted.

Pls help

Comment: You never call `stmt.executeUpdate()`. Also, it's better to do `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e)`. And consider using try-with-resources to ensure resources are closed, even when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statement is never executed. Add code to call execute() method.